# Is it necessary to integrate the testing code within the target project if only use UI Automator?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I was wondering if maybe we could just use a separate project to hold the testing project, instead of integrating it within the target project.

I know we should use Espresso, but in our specific case, our team decided to use UI Automator only. The advantage of using a separate project to hold the testing project is:

1. Building is much faster, since we don't need to compile the whole large target project every time. And only build the separated mock project.
2. Debugging is much faster, in the case of using `./gradlew :connectedAndroidTest` , android would remove the app after test. That means we will have to login the app every time for the new test. In the case of separated project, only the mock project be removed, and the target app keeps still as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UiAutomator to test many different components even some that you are not developing and don't belong to your application (i.e. Home Screen).
Then, you can create an independent project to test whatever you want.